# Is there a way to select last element with a specific CSS class when the elements don't have a parent container?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have below elements rendered dynamically in my html file.

```
<div class="car"></div>
<div class="car"></div>
```

My requirement is to add a style **float:right** inside CSS class **car** for the second element.

I tried below approach but it doesn't work as there is no parent container element. In my case I can't have a parent container in my dynamic form.

```
.car:last-of-type {
    float: right;
}
```

How do I select the second element in my CSS file. Is there any way to achieve what I need? Please help me out with this.

Comment: Your code is totally working. See here: https://codepen.io/cc404/pen/JjbREyN.

Comment: I am using Angular in my application and the above code in the html and css files respectively doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.car ~ .car`. This finds the first element with class name "car" and gets its first sibling with the same class name (`~` is the sibling operator).

```css
.car ~ .car {
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">Car 1</div>
<div class="car">Car 2</div>
```

Comment: I tried the above approach but it only works if there is a parent element for the children. Its not working if they don't have a parent

Comment: @suvenk in this example, the parent is `body`. Every element has at least `body` for a parent.

Comment: I am using Angular in my app and trying to use it exactly as you mentioned but I can't figure out why it isn't working

Comment: @suvenk try `.car ~ .car`?

Comment: @suvenk I meant just `.car ~ .car`. But are you sure you are assigning classes correctly? You need to use the ngClass directive: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass. For example, `<div [ngClass]="'car'"></div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228503/discussion-between-suvenk-and-symlink).

Comment: I tried .car ~ .car and it works. Thank you so much. Could you please elaborate what it means? I mean does it select the last element with that class?

Comment: @suvenk see my edit, I explained it in my answer.

Comment: @MisterJojo it selects the second element. Use `:nth-last-child()` or `:last-child` for larger sets.